# IdentityServer4 {"error":"invalid_client"}

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am using IdentityServer4 (version 3.0.2.0) and facing **no client id** issue. The exact error is

**ERROR| No client with id 'myclientId' found. aborting**

Startup.cs of IdentityServer4 project

```
 services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
               // .AddInMemoryCaching()
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:ApiResources"))
                .AddInMemoryClients(Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:Clients"))
                .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

                    // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
                    options.EnableTokenCleanup = Convert.ToBoolean(Configuration["CleanUp:IsEnabled"]);
                    options.TokenCleanupInterval = Convert.ToInt32(Configuration["CleanUp:Interval"]); // interval in seconds
                });
```

Also, I have sha256 converted client_secret in appsettings.json file, sample appsettings.json

```
    "IdentityServer": {
     "ApiResources": [
      {
        "Name": "myapi",
        "DisplayName": "my api",
        "Scopes": [
          {
            "Name": "mycustomscope"
          },
          {
            "Name": "openid"
          }
        ],
        "ApiSecrets": [
          {
            "Value": "my sha256 converted secret string",
            "Description": "my api"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "Clients": [

      {
        "Enabled": true,
        "ClientId": "myclientId",
        "AccessTokenLifetime": 100000000,
        "ProtocolType": "oidc",
        "RequireClientSecret": true,
        "IdentityTokenLifetime": 300,
        "AuthorizationCodeLifetime": 300,
        "ConsentLifetime": 300,
        "AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime": 2592000,
        "SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime": 1296000,
        "RefreshTokenExpiration": true,
        "AlwaysSendClientClaims": false,
        "ClientName": "myclientId",
        "ClientSecrets": [
          {
            "Value": "my sha256 converted secret string",
            "Type": "SharedSecret"
          }
        ],
        "AllowedGrantTypes": [ "client_credentials", "password" ],
        "AllowedScopes": [ "mycustomscope", "openid" ],
        "RequireConsent": true
      }
    ]

}
```

---

Sample token request from postman/JMeter

**url:** https://myip:port/myappPool/connect/token

**method type:** POST

Parameters are:

```
    { 
      "client_id":"myclientId",
      "client_secret": "plaintext secret",
      "username":"abcdefghijkl",
      "scope":"mycustomscope",
      "device_id":"custom property",
      "password": "mypassword",
      "grant_type":"password",
      "app_version":"custom property",
      "hashed_value":"custom property"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting answer to my own question because I have solved the issue. For me below given field was making an issue. After **removing** this field, the code ran just fine.

`"RefreshTokenExpiration": true`

Turns out, IdentityServer4.Models.Client does not have any boolean field named **RefreshTokenExpiration** but class object.

Comment: Looks like there is such a param, but it is not `true` instead it can be `Absolute` or `Sliding`: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/refresh_tokens.html

Comment: you are right. @mgPePe